# Error while calling MySQL Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Hi when I call this procedure in mysql I get an error:

```
call delete_poll(1,0);
```

procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `prj`.`delete_poll` $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `delete_poll`(IN b_id int,IN rowNumber int)
BEGIN
    declare I int;
    PREPARE STMT FROM " select id into I from poll
    where blog_id=b_id limit ?,1 ";
    SET @start = rowNumber;

    EXECUTE STMT USING @start;

    delete from poll
    where id=I;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Error:

> Undeclared variable: I

Comment: Can you try and remove the `INTO I` part from the `PREPARE STMT` line and see what happens? Could be that mysql doesn't recognize I inside of that prepared statement.

Comment: when I remove this part I get this error : `Unknown column 'b_id' in 'where clause'`,when I remove the part `=b_id` too I dont get any error.But I need the part `INTO I` and the part `=b_id` in my procedure.

Answer (score 0):

STMT doesn't recognize variables declared in procedure( query ) - and i cannot find how to push output values into variable

But i wonder why are you using prepared statment in "prepared statment" ( procedure ) ?

Comment: I used it because I need limit rowNumber,1

Comment: take a look to part 2. ( with between ) http://orkus.wordpress.com/2010/06/29/variable-limit-statement-in-mysql/ if you @i at beginning to row number, and use "@i:=@i - 1) between 0 and 1"